# Force of repulsion between 2 hemisphere of different charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, pressure

> Consider two hemispheres of radius r which are given a uniform surface charge density of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Find the force of repulsion when these two hemispheres are grouped together to complete a sphere .

In this problem I could not get started with how I to find the repulsion because of the different charge densities. 
If they had same charge density then the question would have been easy as it would just have been the electrostatic pressure into area  $F = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0} \pi r^2$.

How can I compute this problem as finding the pressure on a single element due to this non uniform distribution is very difficult. Help please..

Comment: Did you try to do the integral?

Comment: @G.Smith Integral to what ??

Comment: I don’t know if there is a clever way to do this. The straightforward way is to consider how every element of charge $\sigma_1dA$ on one hemisphere exerts force on every element of charge $\sigma_2dA$ on the other hemisphere. That would involve integrating.

Comment: By the way, homework-like problems are off-topic here.

Comment: It's a nice physics problem though. You could ask this question too in a fashion that disguises the homework-like Nature. Which undoubtedly has been done before.

Comment: @descheleschilder Isn't homework like problems allowed if one shows his working ??

Comment: @G.Smith Please help me with it. What function to integrate ?? Actually this problem is ideally for high school students without knowledge of Fourier series and Legendre polynomials.

Comment: You were given this problem in high school?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, In India, I'm in 12 th Grade...( The grade just before the college). I guess it's high school for you.

Comment: @descheleschilder CM for surface density of charge ??? I couldn't understand how that would help ?? The r I used us radius of the spheres.

Comment: Where do you say it's a surface distribution? I thought you meant a three-dimensional charge distribution (which doesn't have to imply the charges will move to the surface). But I think you can use this method too for a surface charge distribution. Just put all the surface charge in the (same) CM of both hemispheres and calculate the force between the two charges in the CM of both hemispheres if they are put together. The total charge on the surface of both hemispheres is easy to calculate as well as their CM. Visiting the 12-the grade this should present no problem for you!

Comment: @descheleschilder Sorry,my mistake I should I mentioned that the surface charge density but nonetheless both the approach / answer are wrong by this method.

Comment: What should be the answer?

Comment: @descheleschilder $ F = \frac{\pi r^2}{2\epsilon_0}\sigma_1\sigma_2$ Although Adam Latosinski , gave the correct answer , I couldn't understand his working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calculate the total force acting on one hempisphere, you can neglect the contributions from self-interatcion, as from the 3-rd Newton's Law, all such contributions will cancel out. You only need to consider only the contributions from the interaction between elements of one hemisphere with elements of the second hemisphere, asnd all such contributions are to be proportional to both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, Because of this the total force also has to be proportional to both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ that is $$ F = \alpha \sigma_1 \sigma_2$$
Knowing the result for $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ allows you to find the value of constant $\alpha$:
$$ F = \frac{\pi r^2}{2\epsilon_0}\sigma_1\sigma_2$$

Comment: What do you mean by the self-interaction?

Comment: How do you know it is,$ F = \alpha \sigma_1 \sigma_2$  ??

Comment: Think about the force between an infinitesimal area on one hemisphere and an infinitesimal area on the other hemisphere. It will be proportional to $(\sigma_1dA_1)(\sigma_2dA_2)$. If you were integrate over the two hemispheres (which appears to be difficult to do analytically), you would obviously get something proportional to $\sigma_1\sigma_2$.

Comment: The unit of $\epsilon_0$ is$Nm^2C^{-2}$ (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity}. If you put all the units together in the expression for the force in this answer, the unit for the force will be $\frac{1}{m^4 N}$, which ain't the unit of force. That's also the unit in my formula, I see now!

Comment: @descheleschilder The unit of $\epsilon_0$ is actually the inverse of what you wrote. The surface charge density $\sigma$ has units $C/m^2$. Adam's formula is correct.

Comment: Yes, I see that now! I took the inverse of $\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: @G.Smith Your statement is quite convincing but.. Is anything with mathematics possible

Comment: @user232243 I don’t know what you’re asking.

Comment: When you said , did you try the Integral... That method... Where you perform a hardcore integral ....

Answer (score -1):

Alright then:

The total charge $q_1$ on $hs_1$ is the surface of $hs_1$ times $\sigma_1$:

$$q_1=2\pi r^2\sigma_1$$

Likewise, the total charge $q_2$ on $hs_2$ is:

$$q_2=2\pi r^2\sigma_2$$

I use the procedure to place the two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ in the two centers of mass of the two hemispheres to find the force between the two hemispheres.

The center of mass of each hemisphere ($CM_{hs}$) with radius $r$ is (see [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/finding-the-centre-of-mass-of-a-hemispherical-shell.459902/)):

$$CM_{hs}=\frac{r}{2},$$

which tells us that the distance between the two charges in the two $CM_{hs}$'s is equal to $r$. Of course, we use

[image]

to find the force. So the force between the hemispheres is:
$$F=\frac {1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}4{\pi}^2 r^4 r^{-2} \sigma_1 \sigma_2=\frac{\pi}{\epsilon_0} r^2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2(N),$$

which differs a factor $2$ with the answer given in the question (if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$), but I have the suspicion that this has to do with this procedure of finding the answer to the question asked.

Comment: This does not give the known answer when $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$.

Comment: This is like an hollow hemisphere....  Only $q_2=2\pi r^2\sigma_2$

Comment: Also note that the force that should e generated should be the same irrespective of the fact wether shere is hollow or not. But according to your solution that would make a difference because the difference between the distance of the CM would vary

Comment: The CM doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Maybe I can better call it the center of the volume of the hemisphere.

Comment: You thought there was charge on the flat bottom of the top hemisphere and on the flat top of the bottom hemisphere (where in fact there is just empty space because the problem is about hemispherical *shells*). But in this case, the force would be infinite because the two flat pieces would be infinitely close to each other. This should make it obvious to you that cannot “average” each hemisphere’s charge into a “center of charge” and then just take the distance between those two points.

Comment: But in the case of two shells without flat bottoms, the edges of the spheres (though infinitesimal thin) are infinitely close together too, giving an infinite force too.

Comment: On the edges, there is a charge density of ${\sigma}' (\frac{C}{m})$, which isn't zero.

Comment: No, because there is an infinitesimal amount of charge “touching” in that case. In your case, there is a finite amount of charge touching.

Comment: The integral is well-defined and finite for spherical shells. It can be fine to have infinitesimal charges infinitesimally close.

Comment: You're right!!!!! (I'm left!!!)

Comment: I edited the answer. Has the factor 2 in my answer disappeared because of the way I tried to solve the question?